# Django - Signal.disconnect does not disconnect the signal

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-2.1

I can't figure out why `disconnect` of `post_save` signal does not work in my project.

When I call `PipedriveSync.objects.first().sync_with_pipedrive()`, it does something and then tries to save some information to the object. Then, the `sync_pipedrivesync` receiver is called which calls `sync_with_pipedrive()` again which invokes `sync_pipedrivesync` etc etc.

To avoid this cycling I've created two methods - `disconnect_sync` and `connect_sync` which should disconnect signal when saving instance and then revoke it. But it doesn't work.

I can see in debugger that the last line in `sync_with_pipedrive` - `self.save(disconnect=True)` invokes the signal.

Do you know what is wrong?

**models.py**

```
class PipedriveSync(TimeStampedModel):
    pipedrive_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_sync = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_sync_response = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_sync_success = models.NullBooleanField()
    last_backsync = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_backsync_response = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_backsync_success = models.NullBooleanField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


    def save(self,disconnect=True,**kwargs):
        if disconnect:
            PipedriveSync.disconnect_sync()
        super().save(**kwargs)
        PipedriveSync.connect_sync()

    @classmethod
    def disconnect_sync(cls):
        post_save.disconnect(sync_pipedrivesync)

    @classmethod
    def connect_sync(cls):
        post_save.connect(sync_pipedrivesync,sender=PipedriveSync)

    def sync_with_pipedrive(self):
        if self.pipedrive_id:
            action = 'update'
        else:
            action = 'create'
        relative_url = self.build_endpoint_relative_url(action)
        payload = self.get_serializer_class()(self.content_object).data
        response = None
        if action == 'create':
            response = PipeDriveWrapper.post(relative_url, payload=payload)
            if response['success']:
                self.pipedrive_id = response['data']['id']
        if action == 'update':
            response = PipeDriveWrapper.put(relative_url, payload=payload)
        try:
            success = response['success']
        except KeyError:
            success = False
        self.last_sync_success = success
        self.last_sync_response = response
        self.last_sync = now()
        self.save(disconnect=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=PipedriveSync)
def sync_pipedrivesync(instance, sender, created, **kwargs):
    instance.sync_with_pipedrive()
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of post_save.disconnect(sync_pipedrivesync)? It should return True if a receiver is actually disconnected. Can you try providing sender argument to disconnect as well?

Comment: It returns just False.

Comment: Then it doesn't disconnect any receivers. Can you try to add the sender argument as well to the disonnect call?

Comment: @OzgurAkcali Thanks, now it works but I thought that sender is not required, that it disconnects signal for all senders.

Comment: disconect method builds an identifier using both the receiver and sender, and disconnects registered receivers that have a matching identifier

Comment: Oh, I see, it does make sense, thanks.